# How to display Date in dd/MM/yyyy format in the View in Asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Controller's Code

```
  int No= Convert.ToInt32(reqCookies["NO"].ToString());  
  Student stud = db.Students.Single(n => n.No == No);
  return View(stud);
```

Im passing the **No** after the user logs In and want the record of that logged In person to be displayed which i have successfully done.My issue is again with the Date.When the record of the Logged In user is displayed the Date of birth is displayed along with the time.Like this ***2/19/2001 12:00:00 AM***, instead i only want the date part and not time something like this ***19/2/2001***.
To achieve this i have tried to convert the date in dd/MM/yyyy format

```
DateTime DOB=stud.DOB.tostring("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Getting Error:**No Overload for method 'ToString()' takes 1 Argument**

Code in my View is like this:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DOB.ToString())</td>
```

And when i try to change the format in the View

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))</td>
```

Getting Error:**No Overload for method 'ToString()' takes 1 Argument**

Where can i make the conversion and how to truncate the time Part from getting displayed.

Comment: `DateTime DOB=stud.DOB.tostring("dd/MM/yyyy");`: you can't assign a string to a DateTime.  This shouldn't compile at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use DisplayFormat in the model to format your date:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
public DateTime myDate { get; set; }
```

And then in the view:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DOB)</td>
```

---

Update:

Alternatively, since the DisplayFor() will simply output the date without any tags, you could just display the date without the use of templated helpers:

```
@Model.myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Or to display in a textbox you could use:

```
@Html.TextBox("Date", Model.myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```